# How I can combine query these data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables.

Table A, store the packages data.
[table a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eE9i.jpg)

```
PackageId | From  | To  | Created
-----------------------------------------
a1        | Japan | USA | 2019/2/22 16:00
a2        | Japan | USA | 2019/2/23 16:00
a3        | Japan | USA | 2019/2/24 16:00
a4        | Japan | USA | 2019/2/25 16:00
a5        | Japan | USA | 2019/2/26 16:00
a6        | Japan | USA | 2019/2/27 16:00
a7        | Japan | USA | 2019/2/28 16:00
a8        | Japan | USA | 2019/3/1  16:00
a9        | Japan | USA | 2019/3/2  16:00
```

Table B, stores tracking history for each package. Multiple tracking records are generated for each package in transit.
[table b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpw4q.jpg)

```
PackageId | StaffId | Action   | UpdateDate
------------------------------------------------
a1        | s1      | Pick up  | 2019/2/23 15:00
a1        | s1      | transmit | 2019/2/24 15:00
a1        | s2      | transmit | 2019/2/25 15:00
a1        | s1      | transmit | 2019/2/26 15:00
a1        | s1      | transmit | 2019/2/27 15:00
a1        | s2      | transmit | 2019/2/28 15:00
a1        | s1      | transmit | 2019/3/1  15:00
a1        | s1      | transmit | 2019/3/2  15:00
a1        | s2      | Deliver  | 2019/3/3  15:00
```

I'm going to create a page with a list of packages and the latest status for each package. Like follow:
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayVXP.jpg)

```
Packages status page                

PackageId | From  | To  | Last Action | UpdateDate
-------------------------------------------------------
a1        | Japan | USA | Deliver     | 2019/3/3  15:00
a2        | Japan | USA | transmit    | 2019/3/4  15:00
a3        | Japan | USA | transmit    | 2019/3/5  15:00
a4        | Japan | USA | transmit    | 2019/3/6  15:00
a5        | Japan | USA | transmit    | 2019/3/7  15:00
a6        | Japan | USA | transmit    | 2019/3/8  15:00
a7        | Japan | USA | transmit    | 2019/3/9  15:00
a8        | Japan | USA | transmit    | 2019/3/10 15:00
a9        | Japan | USA | transmit    | 2019/3/11 15:00
```

I already have a SQL query string:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM [Table A] AS A
JOIN
(
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
    FROM [Table B]
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PackageId ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC)
) AS B ON (b.PackageId = A.PackageId)
```

**How I can convert above Sql string to Linq?**

Or

**How I can do query by EF / .Net core?**

Comment: @MichaelRandall Thank you for your suggestion, I modified my post. added what is my problem.

Comment: Awesome work, great update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this class to store the result:

```
public class Result
{
    public string PackageId { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public string LastAction { get; set; }
}
```

And given `aEntries` containing `A`s and `bEntries` containing `B`s and
Using `.Select()`:

```
List<Result> results = aEntries.AsEnumerable().Select(a =>
{
    var lastB = bEntries.OrderByDescending(b => b.UpdateDate)
                     .First(b => b.PackageId == a.PackageId);
    return new Result
    {
        PackageId = a.PackageId,
        From = a.From,
        To = a.To,
        LastAction = lastB.Action,
        UpdateDate = lastB.UpdateDate
    };
}).ToList();
```

Alternatively, using `.Join()`:

```
List<Result> = aEntries.Join(bEntries, 
    a => a.PackageId, 
    b => b.PackageId,
    (a, b) => new Result()
    {
        PackageId = a.PackageId,
        To = a.To,
        From = a.From,
        LastAction = b.Action,
        UpdateDate = b.UpdateDate
    })
    .GroupBy(r => r.PackageId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.UpdateDate).First()).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your way, and have problems: (1) results should be a list. (2) with your way, table a and table b have to be ToList(), too much in database already, I think ToList process data in C# side is not good? (3) I tried to convert your way in to EF query, got errors (red line)

Comment: Hi! (1) If you want to get the list in the end, do a `results.ToList()`. (2) I am sorry about the naming - they absolutely don't have to be `List`s. The can be `IQueryable`s, or `IEnumerable`s, depending on where you want your processing to be. (3) Not sure what do you mean - can you be a bit more specific about the error?

Comment: Using(var db = new ExpressContext())
{
 var query = await db.TableA.Select(a = >
 {
  var lastB = blist.OrderByDescending(b => b.UpdateDate)
                     .First(b => b.PackageId == a.PackageId);
     return new Result
     {
          PackageId = a.PackageId,
          From = a.From,
          To = a.To,
          LastAction = lastB.Action,
          UpdateDate = lastB.UpdateDate
      };
 }
}

Comment: Above is what i mean.

Comment: @rikyotei Still unclear - what is the error you're talking about? I can only guess - I don't think you can `await` `.Select()`.

Comment: the error was Cannot convert a Lambda expression with a statement body to an expression tree

Comment: @rikyotei Hm, perhaps you do need to take this processing out of the database, using `.AsEnumerable()`, for example. Please see the edit.

Comment: @rikyotei maybe give her a try with `.Join()`? (Please see the edit.)

Comment: the first edit works fine, the join one gots wrong result. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

All you should need is this:

```
Packages.Select(p => 
    new { 
       Package = p, 
       LastAction = p.Actions.OrderByDescending(a => a.UpdateDate).FirstOrDefault() 
        })
```

Assuming your EF classes are setup this way:

```
public class Package
{
    public int PackageId { get; set; } 
    public string From { get; set; } 
    public string To { get; set; } 
    public DateTime Created { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Action> Actions { get; set; } 
}

public class Action
{
    public int PackageId { get; set; } 
    public int StaffId { get; set; } 
    public string Action   { get; set; } 
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Why virtual collection?

Comment: @pteberf polymorphism. not directly related to the question just included it with the code snippet.

Comment: *completely* not related. :D